# JavaScript - RegEx for time or a specific string

Tags: javascript, html, regex

In my form I have a field which asks the user what time they would like me to call them.

The code for the input is as follows (excluding the `<form>` tags):

```
<p>
   <label>When can we call you?:</label>
   <br>
   <input type="text" name="contactconvenience" placeholder="HH:MM or &#34;anytime&#34;" onchange="checkCallTime()">
</p>
<div id="callbackwarn"></div>
```

I want to use a RegEx to check whether the user has entered a time in the format HH:MM or the specific string "anytime", but the code I'm using doesn't work.

```
var callback = /^\d{2}([:]\d{2})$/;

var callbackanytime = str.match(/anytime/g);

function checkCallTime() {
    var valid = true;

    if ((!callback.test(document.bookingsform.contactconvenience.value)) || (!callbackanytime.test(document.bookingsform.contactconvenience.value))) {
        document.bookingsform.contactconvenience.style.border = "1px solid red";
        document.getElementById("callbackwarn").innerHTML = "Enter a time in the format HH:MM or type \"anytime\".";
        document.bookingsform.contactconvenience.title = "Please enter a time in the format HH:MM or type \"anytime\".";
        document.getElementById("callbackwarn").style.display = "block";
        valid = false;
    } else {
        document.bookingsform.contactconvenience.style.border = "1px inset #EBE9ED";
        document.bookingsform.contactconvenience.style.borderRadius = "2px";
        document.getElementById("callbackwarn").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

As you can see I have use two separate RegEx expressions, one for matching a time in the format HH:MM; and the other for matching the specific string "anytime".

In the function itself, I'm using the `||` to see `if` either of the RegExs have been matched or not.

NB: I am aware that I'm using the `onchange` rather than `onsubmit`, the `<form>` tag consists of the `onsubmit` calling on a master function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumming 00:00 for midnight;

```
var callback = /^(([01]\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d)|anytime)$/;

if (!callback.test(document.bookingsform.contactconvenience.value))
{
   // error code
}
```

Comment: This isn't working, if I type in arbitrary characters it won't show the error. I removed the `||` and now just using your one RegEx. Any ideas?

Comment: Yep, that isn't working for me. I even copied and pasted your code, still nothing.

Comment: Works ok for me? http://jsfiddle.net/alexk/4AZqs/ (must click out of the input to raise the event)

Comment: How peculiar, I copied and pasted your jsfiddle code and now it works perfectly. There must've been some mistyped code which I failed to pick up in the error code area of the function. Works perfectly now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an AND `&&` not an OR `||` between the two test:

```
if ((!callback.test(document.bookingsform.contactconvenience.value)) 
    && 
    (!callbackanytime.test(document.bookingsform.contactconvenience.value))) {
```

NOT (A OR B)  <=> NOT A AND NOT B

You could also use an unique regex:

```
/^\d{2}:\d{2}|\s*anytime\s*$/;
```

Comment: I changed it and this didn't work. I then tried your unique RegEx and still didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the value of `contactconvenience`.

Comment: I think `None`? I haven't given the tag a `value` attribute.

Comment: @RoyalSwish: I meant the value when you enter the function.